# How to retrieve Year-Month without leading Zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datepart

How can I create a Year Month column from a "full date" source column without the leading zero?

For instance, I need:
2023-1,2023-2,2023-3

instead of:
2023-01,2023-02,2023-03

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
    CONCAT(YEAR(QUOTE_DATE),'-',MONTH(QUOTE_DATE)) AS Year_Month
```

Comment: Please ta your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: `Concat(year(GetDate()), '-', month(GetDate()))` returns 2023-7, so what is your question, please?

Comment: Are you looking for some thing like this http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/2517

Comment: It seems like you're answering the question in your question... You should be using an answer to answer your question.

Comment: If the column is a datatime datatype, it doesn't have an inherent format. You can format it when you select from it with a pretty simple `format` command like: `select format (DateColumn, 'yyyy-M')`